# Не подключается календарь DatePick jQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, подключить календарь.
Вот такой код работает нормально, если убрать параметры:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
 $(function() {

              $('#getSetInlinePicker').datepick({multiSelect: 4, showTrigger: '#calImg'});

});
 </script>
```

С параметрами `{multiSelect: 4, showTrigger: '#calImg'}` появляется сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @Tatiana Bokareva, если вас не затруднит, укажите, какое сообщение об ошибке появляется? Или вы его предлагаете его нам угадать?  
Желательно было бы увидеть еще ссылку на плагин.

Comment: спасибо ))) мне уже подсказали заключить мой код в literal, я всегда забываю про эту опцию

Comment: @Tatiana Bokareva, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: Раз речь зашла про literal\`ы, то тогда стоило сразу сказать что используется шаблонизатор. Без него (без шаблонизатора) ваш код должен был отработать как надо